# Multiple pipenv environments

Tags: python-3.x, pipenv

We deploy to multiple environments using `pip-tools` to create three different requirements files from their associated `.in` source files: `requirements.txt`, `dev-requirements.txt`, and `web-requirements.txt`. But I would rather use `pipenv` because it seems to me that it handles dependency problems better on my other projects.

Can I just do:

```
extras_require={
    'dev': load_requirements('dev-requirements.txt'),
    'web': load_requirements('web-requirements.txt'),
}
```

in `setup.py`, then when deploying in a Web context do `pipenv install --dev --ignore-pipfile '-e .[web]'`, or in a development context do `pipenv install --dev --ignore-pipfile '-e .[dev]'`?